# ImportError: No module named hmmlearn.hmm python 2.7

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, hmmlearn

- 1. I got this error in python script:
- from hmmlearn.hmm import
- GaussianHMM I know I need some libraries thats why I ran following

  ```
   git clone git://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn.git  
   pip install -U --user hmmlearn
  ```

I getting stuck because of this problem. I didn't get any solution, I tried google and many commands but problem still happen.

Comment: Could you please add the traceback you were seeing as a reference for future users?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by cloning the repository and running:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like according to the git-hub page of the repo it requires specific versions of some packages. Make sure you do a pip upgrade for all those packages

- Python >=2.6
- numpy >= 1.9.3
- scipy >= 0.16.0
- scikit-learn >= 0.16

then try it will work

to upgrade a package do simple 
`pip install --upgrade <package-name>`